# c# Windows Service - subscribe to realtime events (notifications) from a external source

Tags: c#, windows-services, amazon-sqs, pusher

I have a `C#` windows Service installed in a **customer server** that does the following tasks:

1. Listen to a SQL Broker service for any `insert` / `update` in 3 tables and then POST data to an API method so remote server gets updated with latest. (using `SqlTableDependency`)
2. Polling method every 5 minutes to verify / validate that on remote server these 3 tables have same data. (In case the SQL Broker service is not working)
3. Starts a SelfHosted WebAPI server (this doesn't work because customer doesn't allow server to be exposed to Internet)

This last `selfhosted` task was implemented so that from an application it can request to the customer server to perform some updates on a table.

I would like to know if there is a way to subscribe the windows service to a realtime broascast engine / service such `Pusher` or `AWS SQS`, etc. The idea behind is that I can trigger tasks in the remote customer windows service from an outside application.

Any idea if this is a doable thing? If I can do this I even can get rid of the Polling task in the windows service because now I can get the windows service to push information to the API based on an event that I can trigger from an external source.

Comment: I think you can use Pusher and subscribe to whatever channel  it is you need. I would just use a Console application that is always listening. I don't know about a windows service. It doesn't seem like the right tool for that, but I don't really know if that could work, somehow.

Comment: I went the AWS way. Seems it's working pretty nice and with the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best workaround but seems to be working pretty nice.

What I did was to implement in the Windows Service an infinite loop with a Long polling call to a AWS SQS, having the max Receive message wait time parameter in SQS to 20 seconds. What this allowed me is to reduce the empty response messages and also reduce cost for requests to SQS service to only one every 20 seconds.

If a message comes in when the long polling is beging handled then inmediatly the long polling stops and the message is received.

Because the messages sent frequency is not that big, lets say on every 20 seconds I receive 1 then:

- 3 request messages every minute
- 180 per hour
- 4,320 per day
- 103,680 per month

And AWS Pricing is $0.40 per 1 million so that will be practically free.